# Adding the Publications to Tridion User Groups using Core Service

Tags: core-service

We are working on Tridion User group Reconciliation. So, we are checking if there is a possibility to add the Publications to users groups using Tridion Core Service.
Kindly help with this.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if the UI can do it, then CoreService can do it. The UI uses the CoreService.

Comment: Hi Nuno,Thanks for your reply. Can you provide some code reference to add the list of publications to the user groups through core service.

Comment: Your question is “is it possible”, and the answer to that is yes. In typical Stack Exchange model, please show what you tried and where you are stuck, and the community will step in to help.

Comment: Please, can you show the specific piece of code that you've tried? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - this link describes how to ask a question.

Answer (score 8):

You can download the Core Service API reference documentation [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-9E83FE0C-F650-451F-BEB3-7960A4925D90#docid=GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF&filename=GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF). If you look at the documentation you can see that the Groups are represented by the `GroupData` class. In GroupData, you can set the User's group membership by using the `GroupMemberships` property and each membership is represented by the `GroupMembershipData` class. In  GroupMembershipData you'd want to add the publications using the `Scope` property in GroupMembershipData.

[image]

This [answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/7883/1587) might help you too.

Comment: Hi Sabarish. Great to see you welcoming a new contributor and pointing them to the help. Thanks for that. Could I suggest that you move your first paragraph to a comment? That will help people focus on the technical content of your answer.

Comment: Hi Dominic! Thanks for your comment.  Moving the first paragraph to a comment makes sense. I'll do that.